# Using npm package in Meteor via cosmos:browserify

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, reactjs

I'm trying to load Radium (which is a javascript library for inline css) following instructions [here](http://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/client-npm/).

In `app.browserify.js`: `Radium = require("radium");`.

In `package.json`: `"radium": "0.13.4"`

However when I try to use Radium in js in the app, the inline css doesn't work. Chrome dev tool indicates that `Radium = module.exports(ComposedComponent).`.

I'm assuming this should be an object, considering that ReactPIXI that I loaded the same way, works just fine, and the dev tool says `ReactPIXI = Object {factories: Object}`.

Here is my code:

```
AppBody = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData, Navigation, State, Radium.StyleResolverMixin,   
  Radium.BrowserStateMixin],

render: function() {
  var self = this;
  var styles = {
    base: {
      color: this.state.fontColor,
      background: 'red',
    states: [
      {hover: {background: 'blue', color: 'red'}},
      {focus: {background: 'pink', outline: 'none', color: 'yellow'}}
    ]

    //also tried
    //':hover': {background: 'blue', color: 'red'},
    //':focus': {background: 'pink', outline: 'none', color: 'yellow'}
  },
  primary: {
    background: 'green'
  },
  warning: {
    background: 'purple'
  }
};


var items = this.state.items.map(function(item, i) {
  return (
      <div>
        <div style= {[styles.base, styles['warning']]} key={item}>
      // also tried <div style = {this.buildStyles(styles)} key={item}>
          {item}
        </div>
        <button style = {[styles.base, styles['warning']]} onClick={update} >Remove</button>
      </div>
  );
}.bind(this));
return (
       {items}
     )
```

Comment: Are you still having this problem javvva if so I will try to take a crack at it tonight.

Comment: Yes still couldn't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue last night with my setup.  I suspect this is entirely a loading order problem.  Meteor loads folders and items in folders in a very specific order.  I would review http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp again and put 00- or 01- in front of the folder names to ensure they are loading in the order you want them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by wrapping the React.createComponent with Radium as instructed in the [Radium](http://projects.formidablelabs.com/radium/) documentation. Instead of using the mixins, the code now looks like this and it works as intended.

```
AppBody = Radium(React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData, Navigation, State],

render: function() {
  var self = this;
  var styles = {
    base: {
      color: this.state.fontColor,
      background: 'red',
    ':hover': {background: 'blue', color: 'red'},
    ':focus': {background: 'pink', outline: 'none', color: 'yellow'}
  },
  primary: {
    background: 'green'
  },
  warning: {
    background: 'purple'
  }
};


var items = this.state.items.map(function(item, i) {
  return (
  <div>
    <div style= {[styles.base, styles['warning']]} key={item}>
      {item}
    </div>
    <button style = {[styles.base, styles['warning']]} onClick={update} >Remove</button>
  </div>
);
}.bind(this));
  return (
        {items}
      )
)}));
```

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out,  remember to mark your own answer as the accepted one.